# Web3.py is contract deployed correctly and chain synced?

Tags: web3.py

I'm trying to deploy a contract via web3.py on a local test chain.

```
def deploy_contract(w3, file_path, contract_name, gas=2000000):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        source = f.read()
    compiled_sol = compile_source(source, output_values=['abi', 'bin'])
    contract_ID = [s for s in list(compiled_sol.keys()) if s == f'<stdin>:{contract_name}'][0]
    contract_interface = compiled_sol[contract_ID]
    transaction = {
        'from': web3.eth.default_account,
        'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(web3.eth.default_account),
        'gasPrice': w3.eth.gas_price,
        'gas': gas,
    }
    tx_hash = w3.eth.contract(
        abi=contract_interface['abi'],
        bytecode=contract_interface['bin']).constructor().transact(transaction)

    tx_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
    address = tx_receipt.contractAddress

    print(f"Deployed {contract_name} of {file_path} to address {address}")
    return web3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=contract_interface['abi'])

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('http://' + HOST + '/rpc'))
middleware = construct_sign_and_send_raw_middleware(data["PrivateKey"])
web3.middleware_onion.add(middleware)
web3.eth.default_account = Web3.to_checksum_address(data["WalletAddress"])

test = deploy_contract(web3, "test.sol", "test")

print(test.functions.testbool().call())
```

while transact does somewhat work, it does not return the bool value for me. the corresponding contract is simply

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract test{
    bool public testbool = false;
}
```

this results in the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Documents/vms/venvs/web3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/web3/contract/utils.py", line 111, in call_contract_function
    output_data = w3.codec.decode(output_types, return_data)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/Documents/vms/venvs/web3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/eth_abi/codec.py", line 162, in decode
    return cast(Tuple[Any, ...], decoder(stream))
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/Documents/vms/venvs/web3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 131, in __call__
    return self.decode(stream)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/Documents/vms/venvs/web3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/eth_utils/functional.py", line 45, in inner
    return callback(fn(*args, **kwargs))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/Documents/vms/venvs/web3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 224, in decode
    self.validate_pointers(stream)
  File "/home/user/Documents/vms/venvs/web3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 218, in validate_pointers
    decoder(stream)
  File "/home/user/Documents/vms/venvs/web3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 131, in __call__
    return self.decode(stream)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/Documents/vms/venvs/web3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 250, in decode
    raw_data = self.read_data_from_stream(stream)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/Documents/vms/venvs/web3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 389, in read_data_from_stream
    raise InsufficientDataBytes(
eth_abi.exceptions.InsufficientDataBytes: Tried to read 32 bytes, only got 0 bytes.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Documents/vms/htb/magic_vault/ape.py", line 45, in <module>
    print(test.functions.testbool().call())
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/Documents/vms/venvs/web3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/web3/contract/contract.py", line 305, in call
    return call_contract_function(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/Documents/vms/venvs/web3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/web3/contract/utils.py", line 129, in call_contract_function
    raise BadFunctionCallOutput(msg) from e
web3.exceptions.BadFunctionCallOutput: Could not transact with/call contract function, is contract deployed correctly and chain synced?
```

i feel like the mistake is in the contract deployment process.

**EDIT**

it seems to work on the sepolia chain. so i guess the problem isn't me but the chain.

Comment: @ruby_newbie, "testbool" is a public boolean variable in the contract. the abi shows to me that testbool is callable: 

abi=[{'inputs': [], 'name': 'testbool', 'outputs': [{'internalType': 'bool', 'name': '', 'type': 'bool'}], 'stateMutability': 'view', 'type': 'function'}]

i feel like the mistake is in the contract deployment process.